# Loaded image doesn't get set in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, base64

I've got the following app (picture below)
In this app I load base64 strings from a rest api to display the images. the first two get set properly but the last one doesn't work. Just before they get set I log the src too console and it shows me a preview when I hover over it (pic below).

The angular code (which works for the first 2 files) is the following:

```
 getSessions() {
    this.sessionService.getSessions().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.sessions = data
        console.log(data),
        this.sessions.forEach(session => {
          session.sessionImgUrl = 'data:image/png;base64,' + session.sessionPhoto?.image.data;
          if(session.sessionPhoto.title == 'test') {
            console.log(session.sessionImgUrl)
          }
        })
```

HTML:

```
      <img mat-card-image height="150px" [src]="session.sessionImgUrl" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try processing it using DomSanitiser, it's probably being sanitised out https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer `constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
` `session.sessionImgUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl( 'data:image/png;base64,' + session.sessionPhoto?.image.data );`

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: Does it work in this (i.e. is it actually a valid image?) https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Comment: Yes, it even gets back to Angular and as console.log i can just see the preview